# what does express.favicon() do

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to know what express.favicon() does.
I seared and could not get the  reasoning.

can any one explain me on this.

```
app.use(express.favicon());
```

I read some link that this command will do a ignore of GET/favicon.ico.
I am looking for understanding more about this like?where is the function: express.favicon() defined and all those information, I did checked in the expresss website could not find the declaration/definition of this function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It [defines a favicon for your application](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/favicon.html). Passing no path to a favicon will serve up the express favicon by default.

Comment: Thank you , I saw that link . so , when we say express.favicon(). is it default facicon definition is taken?? and also what is the default definition.pl clarify this basic question..also, when we say app.use (express.favicon()) means by default any get with favicon will be calling this right?

Comment: @TheLearner: Yes, the default favicon is used when you don't pass your own. (I think I said that.) And yes, that means any request for a favicon will call that.

Comment: that is what I am looking for where can I get the "default favicon" definition also where can I get information like this in expressAPI guide ....

Comment: @TheLearner: Like I said and it says, it's the express.js favicon. If you want to know what it looks like, just look at it yourself.

Comment: One reason, this function exists is, that otherwise you'll get a 404 request (and probably a log entry) when the browser tries to fetch a favicon.

Comment: Now , Express by default don't support this middleware , you have to installed this middleware separately.
 Most middleware (like favicon) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, it loads the /favicon.ico file from your site (like it would if you have the static handler loaded) but then caches it.

So, the advantage of using this over just the static handler is that it caches it more.

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/favicon.html